# Native crash reporting for Expo deployed to Android?

Tags: android, react-native, crash, expo, crashlytics-android

I have released an Expo app and now need to remotely deduce the cause of errors. I've exported both an Android and iOS build from Expo with `expo build:ios` or `:android` and have deployed them to users via Google play console and iTunes Connect.

A user reported a crash on Android, but in my Google Play console I see no evidence of a crash under "Vitals." This is probably because the app is bundled under the many layers of expo.

I need a way of seeing this crash, so Ive looked at [Bugsnag](https://www.bugsnag.com/blog/bugsnag-react-native#:%7E:text=Share%20this%20post%3A&text=Bugsnag%20for%20React%20Native%20allows,bugs%20that%20impact%20your%20users.), [Sentry](https://docs.expo.io/guides/using-sentry/) and others, but I don't understand whether they will work for this use case.

Will these crash analytics tools give me info if I'm deploying a compiled Android build? Or is this a pre-compile solution?

Answer (score 2):

One of the projects I worked with uses a combination of React Native and Expo to create Android and iOS versions of the app. The app is released in Google Play and Apple's App Store.

We experienced similar limitations with the crash reporting in Android Vitals and use Sentry for the error reporting. The crashes appear as errors in Sentry. They include additional information such as network requests and responses which can help debug some of the errors.

AFAIK Sentry still offer a free tier that a single developer can use. They and others offer paid-for services. One to consider is RayGun https://raygun.com/blog/react-native-monitoring/ (I've not tried it however the documentation looks like it may suit your needs).

PS: I just discovered that Expo endorse using Sentry https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-sentry/ which is an encouraging indication Sentry should be suitable.

Answer (score 0):

I've had joy with Bugsnag. It managed to flag up a number of issues, where all I saw in Google Play console was a crash - or sometimes nothing at all.

One thing to bear in mind, with new releases of the Expo SDK, Bugsnag have to produce a package to use with that version - so if you're an early adopter of new SDK releases there may not be a Bugsnag package available for that version. That said - my experience is that they are pretty quick to produce these packages and their general developer support is excellent.

I've also used Sentry, and that's also excellent. Of the two, Bugsnag probably has the better interface for when you're examining reports of issues, but my impression is that Sentry is significantly easier to implement.

Guides for using with EXPO:

- https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-sentry
- https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/react-native/expo